# Xamarin C# Set View width to % percentage of screen Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have this Button that I want to be 25% of the screen width, and square. I have seen some methods of making grids but it has not worked out well. Anyone have any input on the matter?
Any more context needs to be described?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Android.Support.Design` packages also provides a nice new layout type called `PercentRelativeLayout`.

You can get it by adding the [`Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent/) to your project.

This will enable you to add the `PercentRelativeLayout` to your layout like:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%" />
     <!-- more views here -->
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

You can find [more information about this layout in the Google API docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

Comment: nice. Didn't know this exists :D

Comment: It is pretty neat, this allows you to do all the Relative stuff and flattening your layout AND do percentage widths and margins.

Comment: Wow aspect ratio as well!

Comment: This seems very promising.

Comment: A better alternative nowadays is ConstraintLayout, which can achieve the same, just with a lot more power to the dev.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a horizontal `LinearLayout` and set the `layout_weight` of the button to .25 and add an empty view with a weight of .75. Note: Set `layout_width` to 0.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:text="MyButton" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".25" /> 

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".75" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want something squared, you have to create a custom layout like:

```
public class SquareLayout : LinearLayout
{
    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        var width = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        var height = MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (height == 0 && width == 0)
        {
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }

        if (height == 0)
        {
            height = width;
        }
        else if (width == 0)
        {
            width = height;
        }

        if (width > height)
            width = height;
        else
            height = width;

        base.OnMeasure(
            MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly),
            MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly)
        );
    }

    protected SquareLayout(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
    }
}
```

And then use your Layout in your axml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <mynamespacelowercase.SquareLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".25">
        <Button
            android:text="MyButton" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 
    <mynamespacelowercase.SquareLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".75" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can modify your custom layout to calculate the width depending on a percentage. Then you wouldn't need the empty view and layout weight.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses.

I found this was the easiest.

```
var metric = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
width = (int)(metric.WidthPixels * .25);
```

Then I set the width in the `LayoutParameters`.